# How to convert this array element in a string in typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have this array called fieldlist which is coming from the below http.get request in angular 2 component. 
I have declared it like this .

```
                   fieldlist: string[] = [];
```

then I assigned its value using iteration of json resposne.

```
               this.http.get(getform_endpoint,requestOptions).map((res: 
                                        Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                          res => { 

                   this.FormData = res.schema;


                     res.fields.forEach(element => {
                         this.fieldlist.push(element);
                     });


          });
```

Now in another function like this

```
         create_hidden_qp() {


            let elementsnamevalue = this.fieldlist.join();
            console.log("hello", this.fieldlist.join());

      }
```

when I convert it to string using this lines it gives me blank "" response

but when I print it like this

```
                 console.log("hello", this.fieldlist);
```

I am able to see the perfect array like this.

```
           hello[] 0 :"userroleid" 1: "ruletype" 2: "employeeid"
```

So what I am missing?

A) wrong declaration? 
b) wrong assigment? 
c) wrong access to array elements?

Comment: I have tried this.fieldlist[0], this.fieldlist[1] etc, but its undefined. I have tried this.fieldlist.tostring() but its also gives me blank response. What I am missing?

Comment: option d), wrong timing. You probably try to access the `fieldlist` before the response has completed. Remember that JavaScript, and with it TypeScript are `async` languages

Comment: The `join` function needs an argument to join an array. Try using something like `join(' ')`

Comment: @PierreDuc  Yup that may be a new case but then why I am able to read when printing it        raw like this?           console.log("hello", this.fieldlist);

Comment: @trichetriche I tried using join(' ')  but again its blank response.

Comment: @Jaydeep because the console holds a reference and will actually *update* when the data does come through

Comment: @BradleyDotNET not sure if the console is using a reference for strings though

Comment: ok then how to make sure that I got it before I need it? Should I convert it asap after getting it in response?

Comment: Jaydeep, then you are calling the log before the response is there, as @PierreDuc suggested

Comment: @trichetriche Now once I have joined them just after getting the response, as PierreDuc Suggested. I am able to get the correct ouput 
using this. 
 console.log("Hello this is array" , this.fieldlist.join());
Now How to ensure that it is aviaible when I am calling this another function.

Comment: @PierreDuc should post an answer and you should validate it then !

Comment: yes  I am updating question for more information,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `create_hidden_qp` after your request has finished:

```
this.http.get(getform_endpoint,requestOptions).map(r => r.json()).subscribe(res => { 
  this.FormData = res.schema;

  res.fields.forEach(element => {
    this.fieldlist.push(element);
  });

  this.create_hidden_qp();
});
```

Comment: This has make sure that I got the value when needed. Amazing answer. Thank you all.

Comment: But I am still curios to know that why after USING  .join I am not able to get value but when I print it as raw, got it. Is it because I just passed by value to console as opposed to passing by reference when I am able to see it.

Comment: @Jaydeep Yes, that's a thing of the console, you just log a reference, and once you actually open the array in the console, your request has already finished, and it will show the filled array :)

Comment: Ok so lesson learned is while using async language, Don't delay assignment and conversion as it my defer.